# How to run parallel optuna optimizations programmatically?

Tags: python, optuna

I am using python 3.10.

I tried `threading` module. But it does not improve overall calculation time because of python gil afaik.

I tried `n_jobs` parameter of `study.optimize` but it didn't work for me. The optimization routine uses a unique instance of a class. When `n_jobs` parameter is used, a single instance seems to be manipulated by different runs of the study.

I can successfully run py file using multiple command windows but it is cumbersome for 16 threads.

Any suggestions are appreciated.